# close() was never explicitly called on database exception recieved in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**"InitDatabase()"** is called **"inserRecord()"** but it shows exception every time and in **insertRecord()** i have also called **closeDatabase()** in which i have code to close DB(database).

#### 1. Error while inserting data RunTime:

In starting of program i enter records using **insertRecord()** which works fine but at run time when i used to insert the record it returns new row id but when i `select * from table` then it will not showing that last inserted record

#### 2. Store Cursor in HashMap:

is it good to store cursor in hashmap further if needed in that app.

```
public SQLiteDatabase initDatabase(){
    Log.v("XIG","creating or opening database.");
    db_helper= new DatabaseHelper(context,dbname,1);
    DB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(dbname,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    DB.setVersion(1);
    DB.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    DB.setLockingEnabled(true);
    DB = db_helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return DB;
}


public void insertRecord(String Table,String columnId[],String value[],String typeOfValue[]){
    initDatabase();
    Log.v("XIG","creating new record.");
    ContentValues new_record = new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0; i<columnId.length; i++){
        if(typeOfValue[i].equals("INT")){
            new_record.put(columnId[i],Integer.parseInt(value[i]));
        }
        else{
            new_record.put(columnId[i],value[i]);
        }
    }
    long rowid;
    try{
        DB.beginTransaction();
        rowid = DB.insert(Table,null,new_record);
        DB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally{
        DB.endTransaction();
    }
    Log.v("XIG","inserted rowid in "+Table+": "+rowid);
    closeDatabase();
}
```

#### Exception:

```
initDatabase() method shows exception :
07-12 13:15:32.415: E/SQLiteDatabase(13643): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.app/databases/mydb3' 
07-12 13:15:32.415: E/SQLiteDatabase(13643): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

Answer (score 1):

After  **DB.setTransactionSuccessful();**

you have to commit it by using,   **DB.commit();** then definitely it will works.

You can Store cursor data into the List of MashMap by using code below

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> select(
        String tableName, String[] fields, 
        String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor =      // get data by firing query
    cursor.moveToFirst();

  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(i);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
            map.put(fields[j], cursor.getString(j));
        }
        mapList.add(map);
    }

    return mapList;
}
```

Accept this answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but DB is an object of SQLiteDatabase and has no commit method.

Comment: try by calling     initDatabase();  inside try block before DB.beginTransaction(); method call. And in finally block first DB object is not null and only then call DB.closeTransaction() method

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably not in this function. Your program opens the database somewhere and does not close it before this function is called, which tries to "open" the already-open database..

as your error log says

`Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here`

Answer (score 0):

The close should be inside the finally block. If there was an exception it won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to open and close your database on every update.

Open the database **once** when your application starts up, and don't ever bother closing it. Reuse a single database connection throughout; your code is far simpler this way, and you don't lose anything.

Comment: Thanks graham please tell me is there any way to find that database is already open or not i open database with context.openOrCreateDatabase which is not telling me if it is already opened or not. I am asking this because webview and my program opens database many times so, if there any function to know that db already open i will not open db anymore.

Comment: ok graham i am doing this by setting a variable that database is already opened.